# How to add data to .db file?

Tags: java, android

I use sqliteassethelper to retrieve the data, but I don't know how to import the data into that database, it's stored in assets/databases/...how should I search them with keywords?

Should I create a new sql management java file or use it with the declared file sqliteassethelper? My .db file already has a table that I can import data into

Answer (score 0):

As the readme file of the [github repo](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#this-project-is-no-longer-maintained) of sqlite-asset-helper states:

> An Android helper class to manage database creation and version management using an application's raw asset files.

Meaning, only the creation and version management of the database itself can be handled with it. It doesn't provide functionality to load or retrieve data.

You should use another library, not only because of this. The last change of the library was made 9 years ago and **the library is no longer maintained**.

Android itself already provides a library to work with SQLite Databases in `android.database.sqlite`. A extensive explanation of how to use this library can be found in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial). The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java) is also worth a read.